# Issue with upload same files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a json object as below:

```
"applicationDocument": [
      {
        "applicationDocumentId": 0,
        "documentTitle": "id.txt",
        "fileSize": 3894,
        "remarks": test1        
      },
      {
        "applicationDocumentId": 0,
        "documentTitle": "id.txt",
        "fileSize": 3894,
        "remarks": test2      
      }
    ]
```

and 2 files with same name and size file (as id.txt above), but content is difference .

Step 1: I can add file from my machine, but not upload to server.
[image]

Step2: after add 2 files
[image]

when click save button, the files is uploaded on server and insert db, but I don't know exactly the which the remark match with which file. Please give me advise How to know the remark parameter in which file ?

Using postman: entity is json object, files are the uploaded file
[image]

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Could you edit it to make it clearer what the problem is, what you want to achieve and also to include the code you have right now too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: please take look again..thanks for your response.